# Base class isn't Deserialized

Tags: c#, json

I am using [Newtonsoft.Json .Net for 4.0](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) for this project

Parent class:

```
public class CLiveThing
{
    private object lawk = new object();

    public Action<double> hp_cur_changed;
    public Action<double> hp_max_changed;

    public double hp_max { get; private set; }
    public double hp_cur { get; private set; }

    public void change_hp_max(double val)
    {
        lock (lawk)
        {
            hp_max += val;
            if (hp_max_changed != null)
                hp_max_changed(hp_max);
        }
    }

    public void change_hp_cur(double val)
    {
        lock (lawk)
        {
            hp_cur += val;
            if (hp_cur_changed != null)
                hp_cur_changed(hp_cur);
        }
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class CPlayer : CLiveThing
{
    public int id { get; private set; }

    public CPlayer(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /*
     * Network
    */

    public string Serialize()
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
    public static CPlayer Deserialize(string val)
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CPlayer>(val);
    }
}
```

**Server** (uses Players.CPlayers to manage all players with a generic collection)

```
Players.CPlayers.Serialize()
```

*Players.CPlayers.Serialize serializes all players in the server's memory, one per line*

Like so:

```
public static string Serialize()
{
    players_lock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);
    string str = "";
    foreach (CPlayer player in players.Values)
    {
        str += player.Serialize();
        str += Environment.NewLine;
    }

    players_lock.ReleaseReaderLock();
    return str;
}
```

**Client**

I put a break line in the Players.CPlayers.Deserialize loop, which reverses what the server did.

```
foreach (string line in split)
{
    if (line.Length > 0)
    {
        CPlayer player = CPlayer.Deserialize(line);
        addOrReplace(player.id, player);
    }
}
```

Here's an example of one line:

What goes in:

```
"{\"hp_cur_changed\":null,\"hp_max_changed\":null,\"id\":1,\"hp_max\":100.0,\"hp_cur\":100.0}"
```

What comes out of CPlayer.Deserialize():

[image: out]

It only Deserialized the ID and ignored the properties in the parent class. Which is weird because the server-side did Serialize it properly. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find an official reference why it's working like this but there are at least two way to solve your problem:

Declare your base class property setters as public

```
 public double hp_cur { get; set; }

 public double hp_max { get; set; }
```

Or annotate them with the `JsonProperty` attribute:

```
 [JsonProperty]
 public double hp_max { get; private set; }

 [JsonProperty]
 public double hp_cur { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I had never heared of JsonProperty before, I think that'll do. Thanks!